# React npm start issue - node.js latest version

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I have installed the latest version of node.js and tried to create my very first react application.The applications gets created fine.but when i navigate to the application and try to use the command npm start,it throws an error.I have tried to remove the npm_modules,update npm,npm install create-react-app command.Still the problem persists.Any idea or suggestion will be very helpful!Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what error is thrown exactly?

Comment: Did you install react-native globally with `npm install react-native -g`? If yes, you need to delete it and use `npx`.

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue is resolved..i just had to set my path variable to c:\windows\system32
using the command **PATH=%PATH%;c:\windows\system32**!Thanks for all those who tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you use CRA, it is recommended to use npx instead of npm.

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

Comment: npx create -react-app works fine and the app gets created but when i navigate into that app and give npm start,then it throws an error

Comment: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tweetme2-web@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tweetme2-web@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Govindan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-05T17_00_50_234Z-debug.log  -This is the error message am receiving!